# Pilot won't wall run, but rather wall hangs

Tags: titanfall-2

I'm having an issue with TitanFall2. I'm in campaign mode. It seems for the past bit, my pilot has only been able to wall hang and not wall run. I get my pilot a running start, hit the wall, and it sticks ... stops dead in its tracks. You can hear after a few seconds where there seems to be a "sucking sound", like where the pilot is losing the grip on the wall, then the pilot falls to the floor (or where ever the pilot happens to be hanging over). The only way to get forward momentum is to jump from wall to wall if there are two walls available to bounce back and forth from. The section of the game I'm at (I don't know what to call it) is where you have to phase shift between past and present. I'm in the part of the level where you had to wall run/jump between the two walls as you shifted back and forth. I was unable to wall run, but managed to muscle my way through this part by gaining enough forward distance through jumping. Was a total PITB.

EDIT: I do have it set to auto-sprint, but this has never been an issue.

I've played TF1 and have the mechanics of *how to wall run* down very well. I've gone in and ensured my key bindings are reset back to standard, to ensure there aren't any issues there. The only thing I can figure which might be happening (but seems illogical) is I've recently received the ability to wall hang in Multi-Player mode. I'm wondering if it's bleeding over? I've done some searching on the Interwebz with very limited success.

Comment: That is really strange... Does changing to manual and using SHIFT fix the issue?  The only possible problem I can think of (Aim down sights <-> Wall Hang) should of been fixed when you defaulted settings. - And this is for the PC, correct?

Comment: @NBN-Alex - Changing to manual does not fix the issue. It's on the PC. I may have to close this question, as I think this is a bug. When I *finally* got through the section I'm talking about, wall running works just fine. No clue why it didn't work where I'm talking about.

Comment: I have submitted a ticket with EA Games on this matter, especially since someone else is having the same issue, but not in the same portion of the game. Mod, please close if you feel it needs to be, or I can post a resolution if/when I get something back from EA on it.

Comment: It's better to post an answer once you hear back! :)  There might be other people with the same issue who will search and find your answer!